# SQL String issue

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012

I have this `INSERT` statement,

```
"INSERT INTO [CustomerInfo] (CustomerName, CustomerEmail, CustomerAddress) " +
$"VALUES ('{name}','{email}','{address}')";
```

So as you can see on the 2nd line, i have added `'$'`. This version of the code works, but it's not supported in VS2012.

I'm trying to convert this into something like this but I'm having a lot of issues since it's so very complicated .

```
"INSERT INTO [CustomerInfo] (CustomerName, CustomerEmail, CustomerAddress) " +
"VALUES (''" + name + "', ''" + email + "', ''" + address + "')";
```

This version above doesn't work. Basically i'm trying to make a query without using the `'$'` Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you aware that `$""` is nothing but a shortcut to `string.Format`? Anyway, both versions are wrong since you should be using parameters to prevent SQL Injection attacks

Comment: You should be using parameterized queries rather than format strings or string concatenation to form your insert queries, to prevent SQL Injection attacks. Learn about [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) and [Parameterized Queries in C#](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp).

Comment: I recommend that you can use [**SqlParameter**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx), to add values for consult by parameters ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Don't* do that at all, it exposes you to SQL injection attacks *and* converions issues. What would a date look like if you tried to pass it using string concatenation? A decimal?

It's actually easier to use parameterized queries :

```
//Create a SqlCommand that can be reused
SqlCommand _cmdInsert;

var sql="INSERT INTO [CustomerInfo] (CustomerName, CustomerEmail, CustomerAddress) " + 
        "VALUES (@name,@email,@address)";
var cmd=new SqlCommand(cmd);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@address", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
_cmdInsert=cmd;
```

Later, you can use the command directly by setting a connection and parameter values :

```
using(var connection=new SqlConnection(theConnectionString)
{
    _cmdInsert.Connection=connection;
    _cmdInsert.Parameters["@name"].Value=someName;
    ...
    connection.Open();
    _cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Parameterized queries pass the strongly-typed values *alongside* the query in the RPC call. A DateTime is passed as a DateTime (or the binary equivalent) to the server, not as a string. This way, there are no conversion errors. No matter what the value contains, it's never mixed with the query itself so it isn't executed. Even if `address` contained `'); drop table Users;--` it wouldn't be executed.

Another option is to use a microORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). Dapper uses reflection to map parameter names and data properties to create and execute parameterized queries:

```
var insertStmt="INSERT INTO [CustomerInfo] (CustomerName, CustomerEmail, CustomerAddress) " + 
        "VALUES (@name,@email,@address)";

connection.Execute(insertStmt, new { name=someName,email=someEmail, address=someAddress});
```

As the project's page shows, you can execute the same query multiple times if you pass an array of parameters :

```
var myItems=new[] 
            {
                new {name=someName,email=someEmail, address=someAddress}
            };
connection.Execute(insertStmt, myItems);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use parameterized queries, for example if you are using ADO.NET, use this:

```
. . .
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("yourConnectionString"))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [CustomerInfo] (CustomerName, CustomerEmail, CustomerAddress)
                        VALUES (@Name, @Email, @Address)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new SqlParameter[]
    {
        new SqlParameter("@Name", name),
        new SqlParameter("@Email", email),
        new SqlParameter("@Address", address)
    });
    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
. . .
```

other sql provider type examples you can find **[here](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp)**.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeap, I've noticed :)